# Generate PHP Variables file from HTML Form

Tags: php, html, forms, file, variables

I currently have a variables.php file like this:

```
<?php
    $rep_name = "John Doe";
    $rep_phone = "555-555-5555";
    $rep_email = "johndoe@email.com";
    $rep_subject = "Agent Contact: JDoe";
    $rep_price = "39.95";
?>
```

I want to create an HTML page with a form that would generate this - would look something like this:

```
<form name="generatevariables" action="generate_variables_file.php" method="post">
    Rep Name:<input name="rep_name" placeholder="John Doe"><br />
    Rep Phone:<input name="rep_phone" placeholder="555-555-5555"><br />
    Rep Email:<input name="rep_email" placeholder="johndoe@email.com"><br />
    Rep Subject:<input name="rep_subject" placeholder="Agent Contact: JDoe"><br />
    Rep Price:<input name="rep_price" placeholder="39.95">
</form>
```

and they would enter their information and click a button that says Generate. That would create the variables.php file and download it to their computer for them to upload via FTP:

```
<?php
    $rep_name = "John Doe";
    $rep_phone = "555-555-5555";
    $rep_email = "johndoe@email.com";
    $rep_subject = "Agent Contact: JDoe";
    $rep_price = "39.95";
?>
```

which could then be uploaded and the variables be called throughout the site, just as I am currently calling the variables at the very top.

Does this make sense? I need for the rep to be able to generate their own variables.php file, the rest of the website depends on the variables.php file for all content that is specific to them.

Thanks.

Comment: You should write the main site correctly to where it pulls the rep information from a db rather than this contrived way of doing things.

Answer (score 0):

You can set an appropriate header to force download, then just echo out the code in plain text:

```
<?php
//generate_variables_file.php
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=variables.php');
header('Content-type: text/plain');

echo '<?php';
echo     '$rep_name = "' . $_POST['rep_name'] . '";';
echo     '$rep_phone = "' . $_POST['rep_phone'] . '";';
echo     '$rep_email = "' . $_POST['rep_email'] .'";';
echo     '$rep_subject = "' . $_POST['rep_subject'] .'";';
echo     '$rep_price = "' . $_POST['rep_price'] .'";'
echo '?>';
```